# Trigger is not updating current record PostgresSQL when record is inserted from hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, triggers

I have one table which stores interview slots with start and end times below is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE INTERVIEW_SLOT (
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    INTERVIEWER INTEGER REFERENCES USERS(ID) NOT NULL,
    START_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- start time of interview
    END_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- end time of interview
    -- more columns are not necessary for this question
);
```

I have created a trigger which will truncate start and end time to minutes below is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
iv_slot_ai() returns trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
raise warning 'cleaning start and end time for iv slot for id: %', new.id;
    update interview_slot set end_time = TO_TIMESTAMP(end_time::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');
    update interview_slot set start_time = TO_TIMESTAMP(start_time::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');
    return new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER IV_SLOT_AI AFTER INSERT ON INTERVIEW_SLOT
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE iv_slot_ai();
```

When I insert a record from psql terminal manually trigger gets hit and updates the inserted record properly.

```
 INSERT INTO public.interview_slot(
interviewer, start_time, end_time, is_booked, created_on, inform_email_timestamp)
VALUES (388, '2022-08-22 13:00:10.589', '2022-08-22 13:30:09.589', 'F', current_date, current_date);
WARNING:  cleaning start and end time for iv slot for id: 72
INSERT 0 1

select * from interview_slot order by id desc limit 1;
 id | interviewer |       start_time        |        end_time         |
----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
 72 |         388 | 2022-08-22 13:00:00     | 2022-08-22 13:30:00     |
```

I have a backend application in spring boot with hibernate ORM. When I insert the record from API call, it gets triggered(i have checked in Postgres logs) but the inserted record does not get updated.

Actually, method which saves records is being called from another method that has this `@Transactional()` annotation.

I have also tried BEFORE trigger but it was also not working.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what is the solution?

Is it because of transactional annotation?

Comment: The trigger should only be executed when the transaction is committed, as that is when the insert is actually happening on the database level. You can test this by adding a delay in the `@Transactional` method and check when the trigger is executed.

Comment: Hi, @XtremeBaumer thanks for replying. I know it is committed after the method is completed. I checked that a new record was created and the trigger was also hit and the actual ID of the row was printed in logs but why dated were not truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OMR might be updating. Use `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger with this somewhat simpler function (w/o the message) using [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```sql
create or replace function iv_slot_ai() returns trigger language plpgsql as
$body$
begin
  new.start_time := date_trunc('minute', new.start_time);
  new.end_time := date_trunc('minute', new.end_time);
  return new;
end;
$body$;
```

Comment: Hi, I have just tried this it not truncating time.

Comment: `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` and `FOR EACH ROW` and still does not truncate time? And BTW the names of the trigger and the trigger function shall better be not the same.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE now it's working from both terminal and backend. And thanks for the trigger function name suggestion I will keep in mind.
Can you explain why only BEFORE/AFTER INSERT was not working?